# configure: error: avcodec headers not found

Tags: software-installation, ffmpeg, libav

I'm compiling a source code that generates following error:

```
checking for avcodec.h... no
checking for libavcodec/avcodec.h... no
checking for ffmpeg/avcodec.h... no
checking for libav/avcodec.h... no
checking for ffmpeg/libavcodec/avcodec.h... no
checking for libav/libavcodec/avcodec.h... no
configure: error: avcodec headers not found! Install FFmpeg or Libav.
```

Installing `ffmpeg` package didn't help me. Which package should be installed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see [here on packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=avcodec.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=yakkety&arch=any), `avcodec.h` is in the `libavcodec-dev` package. Use following command to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev
```

Comment: This, BTW, is a general naming pattern for Debian packages, which is inherited by Ubuntu: packages containing primarily libraries for programmatic use rather than applications / scripts / programs for human use are named `lib*`, and packages containing files for developing with rather than using a package are named `*-dev`. So, whenever you search for the development headers of a library named `foo`, they are likely to be in `libfoo-dev`.

Comment: Great addition, @JörgWMittag.

Comment: You can also look for packages containing `avcodec.h` by executing `apt-file search avcodec.h`…